# quickblox-android jar couldn't find

Tags: android, xmpp, quickblox

In this link http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample they have mentioned `<quickblox-android-sdk>/jars/quickblox-android-sdk-core-2.0.jar and <quickblox-android-sdk>/jars/quickblox-android-sdk-chat-2.0.jar` but in the download folder there is no jar files. Also I surfed more to get these jar but I couldn't get can anyone help to get this jar.

Comment: Download the sample project of QB it contains all jars that a user can use

Comment: https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/archive/master.zip this is the link to download sample projects .but there is no jar

Answer (score 0):

Starting from 2.5 version of QuickBlox Android SDK they were moved to separate repository https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk-releases

So now you also can use Maven style to connect it

Use this guide to check how to connect QuickBlox Android SDK now http://quickblox.com/developers/Android#How_to:_add_SDK_to_IDE_and_connect_to_the_cloud