# quickblox-chat android jar file for eclipse project

Tags: android, eclipse, chat, messaging, quickblox

In my project I want to integrate chat feature.I was done my entire project in eclipse now am trying to integrate quickblox android sdk for chat. But the quickblox guide is showing for android studio when I try for .jar file I couldn't able to find can some one help me with the .jar file for eclipse. I was also checked [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35982038/quickblox-android-jar-couldnt-find) but no use with the answer

Comment: [Go this link and download zip](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk-releases) and then [Read this for jar](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk-releases#jar-installation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First download the jar from [QuickBlox chat for android](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk-releases/tree/master/com/quickblox/quickblox-android-sdk-chat)

You can add a jar in Eclipse by right-clicking on the `Project` → `Build Path` → Configure Build Path. Under `Libraries tab`, click `Add Jars or Add External JARs` and give the Jar what you downloaded

Comment: choose version and then download .jar from the link .